# Can the predicted value vs observed value plot have a slope not equal 1 in a LASSO model?

Tags: multiple-regression, lasso

I was trying to use glmnet package in R to create a lasso regression model. The details of my data are:

Dependent variables $y$: 451 observations, single value for each observation.

Independent variables $x$: 451 observations, 959 values for each observation.

I find the optimal value of $\lambda$ by minimizing the cross-validated mean-squared error. Then I generated the parameters $\beta$ by the respective value of $\lambda$. The number of nonzero parameters is around 20. Finally I generated the predicted values $\hat{y}=\sum\beta x$.   When I make a plot of $\hat{y}$ against $y$, the slope of the plot is smaller than 1. But If I plot $y$ against $\hat{y}$ , the slope is equal to 1.

My questions are:

1. Does that mean my model is flawed? Why the slope of $y$ against $\hat{y}$ is not equal to the inverse of the slope of $\hat{y}$  against $y$?
2. Is that due to the nonlinearity of my data? I know the relationship between $y$ and $x$ is nonlinear.
3. Does that mean my model can be improved by doing some nonlinear transformation on $y$? I was tried to do some sigmoid transform by it doesn't changed the slope.

Many thanks.

Comment: I know nothing about LASSO, but assume that the slope should not equal one. You haven't just flipped the axis of your calibration plot and the slope is >1?

Comment: should be <1, I have the axis flipped! :)

Comment: If I plot Actual vs Predicted value, the slope is equal to 1.